# Deploying Spring Web application with Maven and MySQL in cloud?

Tags: java, mysql, maven, spring-mvc, web-hosting

I have developed a Spring web application using Maven as its build tool and I have MySQL connectivity (DB) to my application. Tomcat is my server for now. So now I need to host this application in cloud.

At the moment I have host it in a **Jelastic** server. But they are offering only 14 day trial period and their cost to my application may take around $40 per month when it comes to commercial account. But that is a unbearable cost for me as Student. So I need to host this application, it is really good if its free, or to a low cost (around $25 per **YEAR**).

Please help me with your ideas It will be really help for me. It would be really pleased for me to host in a server without condition like below.

*** environment will automatically put to sleep after 48 hours of inactivity.**

Thanks in Advanced.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use [AWS Free Usage Tier](http://aws.amazon.com/free/). They provide free instance for 12 month free usage. You need to signup with valid credit card.

AWS Free Instance more details : [AWS Free Usage Tier FAQs](http://aws.amazon.com/free/faqs/)